# Голос за незакрытие вопроса

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, закрытие-вопросов

Когда кто-то считает необходимым закрыть вопрос, он голосует за его закрытие по той или иной причине. Когда нужный порог голосов достигается - вопрос закрывается.

А что если я не согласен с необходимостью закрытия вопроса, как мне проголосовать за **незакрытие** вопроса?

В идеале было бы неплохо иметь способ таким действием увеличить порог необходимых для закрытия голосов.

---

**Meta.SE:** [How about a "Vote not to close" option to counter the "Vote to close"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-about-a-vote-not-to-close-option-to-counter-the-vote-to-close)

Comment: никак, можно плюсануть вопрос

Comment: если повезет, вопрос можно найти в очереди на закрытие и проголосовать там

Comment: но лучше оставить комментарий, в котором объяснить почему вы не согласны с закрытием

Comment: @Grundy что это даст?

Comment: @PavelMayorov Вы имеете в виду в очереди нажать "Оставить открытым"? Интересно, а как это дальше учитывается.

Comment: @alexolut, а не знаю :-) возможно какое-нибудь поведение меняется от рейтинга вопроса

Comment: @alexolut несколько голосов "оставить открытым", внезапно, оставят вопрос открытым.

Comment: @PavelMayorov комментарий - это, конечно, хорошо. Но всё же для закрытия комментарий не является обязательным. И в данном случае хорошо бы видеть симметричность.

Comment: @PavelMayorov где-то описано такое поведение про "оставить открытым"?

Comment: @alexolut для закрытия вопроса, необходимость закрытия которого спорна - нужен комментарий. Для оставления открытым вопроса, необходимость оставления которого спорна - нужен комментарий. Все симметрично.

Comment: @PavelMayorov спорность закрытия появляется только после первого комментария за незакрытие. Для закрытия достаточно выбрать один из предложенных пунктов (без явного комментирования). Я именно это имел в виду, указывая на несимметричность.

Comment: @alexolut для закрытия надо, чтобы с закрытием согласились несколько проверяющих. Для оставления открытым требуется то же самое. Комментарий нужен чтобы донести ваше мнение проверяющим.

Comment: @PavelMayorov и всё таки, у Вас есть информация о том как работает "оставить открытым"? Я не могу найти, где об этом написано.

Comment: Вкрутил ссылку на аналогичный вопрос на метамете.

Comment: @PavelMayorov не оставит открытым. но выбросит из очереди на закрытие, что резко сокращает шанс закрытия.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### По-хорошему, *никак*

#### Нужна ли эта фича?

Голосуют за закрытие, как правило, не кто попало (3к репутации это всё-таки существенный порог) и не просто так (голос всё-таки не анонимен). Можно:

- отредактировать вопрос, сделав акцент на чертах, которые делают вопрос уместным на этом ресурсе
- объяснить свою позицию в комментариях: голосующие читают комментарии к вопросу (особенно если их мало)

...и надеяться, что в очереди проверок его всё-таки оставят (много решений "оставить открытым"), а уже оставившие закрывашку (хотя бы некоторые) отзовут её.

---

### Когда/если вопрос всё-таки закроют

1. Оставить комментарий с объяснением своей позиции (если не сделано ранее).
2. Голосовать за переоткрытие.

---

### Если ничего не работает

Возможно, вы всё-таки зря пытаетесь спасти вопрос и он правда неуместен? Можно поинтересоваться мнением общественности [в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--) или здесь, на Мете.

Comment: Голос анонимен до тех пор пока вопрос не закрыт, насколько я вижу. Более того, причины закрытия могут быть разными у разных закрывающих. И какая будет у какого-то конкретного из них - определить нельзя обычному участнику.

Comment: @alexolut если голос не выгорит, то он всё равно становится недействительным и уже неважно, ответственным быть не за что. Но если он всё-таки срабатывает...

Comment: @alexolut причины закрытия могут быть не только разными у разных закрывающих, **их может быть несколько сразу** (фактически, при этом технически это невыразимо).

Comment: Несколько? Выбрать несколько радио-кнопок? О_о Это достойно вопроса на основном сайте :)

Comment: @alexolut 1) делаем чекбоксы 2) рисуем кастомный стиль чека :)

Comment: @pavel 3) предлагаем в качестве "улучшения" для всех сайтов Stack Exchange.

Comment: Для чего же тогда нужна кнопка "Оставить открытым" в Проверке, о которой упомянул @PavelMayorov?

Comment: @alexolut это кому-то адресовано, или мне?

Comment: @D-side то, что под сообщением - автоматически адресовано автору :) Даже если адресовано кому-то другому.

Comment: @alexolut вот я вас и спрашиваю, к кому тот вопрос :) Потому что механизм этой кнопки в ответе затронут.

Comment: Пардоньте, не заметил. Но всё равно хочу получить описание алгоритма подобной проверки.